# Unable to save select box options in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I am working on my first project using **Laravel 5.1**. Uses a selectbox in a form.

```
  {!!Form::select('animal_parent[]', array('1' =>  'opt1',  '2' =>  'opt2',  '3' => 'opt3', '4' => 'opt4',), null, ['id' => 'animal_parent', 'disabled' => 'disabled', 'multiple' => 'multiple', 'class' => 'form-control'])!!}
```

Selection limited to two options which need to saved in two columns, `male_parent` and `female_ parent` of the `animal` table.

There are no `male_parent` and `female_ parent` element names in the form. Similarly no `animal_parent` field in `animal` table.

Values are set as expected in the code given below. However, the insert command does not reflect the newly set values and throws an error.

> "ErrorException in helpers.php line 671: preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array."

Any help would be much appreciated.

First attempt using mutators

```
public function setMaleParentAttribute()
{
    $parent = Input::get('animal_parent');
    $this->attributes['male_parent'] = intval($parent[0]);
}

public function setFemaleParentAttribute(AddAnimalRequest $request)
{
    $parent = Input::get('animal_parent);
    if (isset($parent[1])) {
       $this->attributes['female_parent'] = intval($parent[1]);
    } else {
        $this->attributes['female_parent'] = intval($parent[0]);
    }
    unset($request->animal_parent);
}
```

Second attempt using the `store()` method in the controller.

```
$animal = new Animal($request->all());
$parent = Input::get('animal_parent');

$animal['male_parent'] = intval($parent[0]);
if (isset($parent[1])) {
    $animal['female_parent'] = intval($parent[1]);
} else {
    $animal['female_parent'] = intval($parent[0]);
}

unset($request->animal_parent);
Auth::user()->animals()->save($animal);
return redirect('animals');
```

Comment: The problem was then solved with a change in UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was then solved with a change in UI. I feel the problem could have been solved using the below method. Hope that helps someone.

```
 $input = $request->all();
    $parent = $input['animal_parent'];

    $input['male_parent'] = intval($parent[0]);
    if (isset($parent[1])) {
        $input['female_parent'] = intval($parent[1]);
    } else {
        $input['female_parent'] = intval($parent[0]);
    } 

    unset($input['animal_parent']);
    $animal = new Animal($input);
    $animal->save();`
```